# How to make the checkboxes to be checked based on some condition in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a loaded DataGrid. In that DataGrid the first column is a CheckBox, and the second column is "Name". Also I have saved one field "Name" in the database . Here I want to make the CheckBox to be checked if the Name is equal to the data which I stored in the database.

Here my problem is that ,I am getting only one CheckBox to to be checked.
ex:[ If my expected result is 1st, 2nd and 3dr CheckBoxes to be checked , But I am getting only the 3rd one as checked. ]

my sample code is

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdProduct.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblproduct = (Label)row.FindControl("lblProduct");
            CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelectAll");

            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
            {
                DataRow r = dt.Rows[rowIndex];

                if (Convert.ToString(r["productName"]) == lblproduct.Text)
                {
                    chkSelect.Checked = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    chkSelect.Checked = false;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if you have the correct label and checkbox reference in each iteration ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution ... Simply removed the else part

```
 else
            {
                chkSelect.Checked = false; }

--
```

thank you all...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am blind. You are looping through the datarows and of course you most likely have only one match. In all other cases it becomes unchecked right after. Use the following:

```
     foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdProduct.Rows)
     {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblproduct = (Label)row.FindControl("lblProduct");
            CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelectAll");

            chkSelect.Checked = false;

            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count || !chkSelect.Checked; rowIndex++)
            {
                DataRow r = dt.Rows[rowIndex];

                if (Convert.ToString(r["productName"]) == lblproduct.Text)
                {
                    chkSelect.Checked = true;

                }
            }

        }
```

Als when comparing strings I recommend http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals(v=vs.110).aspx

COmpared what you are going to do with the data and controls in the grid I also recommend additional validation.